# How to use pytest.lazy_fixture with ids?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to parametrize fixtures using [lazy_fixture](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture) using something like the following piece of code :

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[list_of_something], 
ids=[list_of_ids_for_the_previous_list]
)
def some_fixture(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', [
    pytest.lazy_fixture('some_fixture'),
])
def test_func(arg):
    assert arg == 42
```

Now when I run this using pytest, all the parameters have the same `ids` as in
`test_func[arg0]` but if I had used fixture `some` in the test_func directly like

```
def test_func(some_fixture):
    assert some_fixture == 42
```

then I'm able to see all the `ids` when each parameter from the fixture is used.

My question is : how do I use `ids` along with `lazy_fixture`s in `mark.parametrize`?